# Symfony: No route found for "GET/content/articles/changeArt......"

Tags: symfony

I have a button that contains a link to another page, and pass some variables from the twig template to the controller action of that page :

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" title="modifier l'article">
                                <a href="{{ path('changeArticle',{'id': id,'title':titre,'content':corps,'date':pub|date('d/m/Y')}) }}" style="color: #ffffee;text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                            </button>
```

The variables pass to the action successfully  but I get an error :

```
 No route found for "GET /content/articles/changeArt/3/test3/%3Ci%3E%3Cu%20style=%22background-color:%20rgb%28255,%20255,%200%29;%22%3Esdfghyujhgrertjr%22%5Ekrjthbkrkjgjgrhgiebgfjkebvkebvkezbkzbkdzbdkzbckdszb%20sdnckdzb%20nc,de%3C/u%3E%3C/i%3E/11/04/2017" (from "http://127.0.0.1/PFE_CNAM/web/content/articles")
```

(the variable '**content**' its of type **BLOB**, and I start geting this error when i changed its type, because before **when it was of type text,this action was working pretty good**).
Here is the action code :

```
 /**
     * @Route("/content/articles/changeArt/{id}/{title}/{content}/{date}",defaults={"id": 0,"title": 0,"content": 0,"date": 0},name="changeArticle")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function changeArticleAction($id,$title,$content,$date)
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();
        $search = $session->get('user');

        $gestAcces = $session->get('acces');
        $gestEtat = $session->get('etatUser');
        $gestCont = $session->get('contenu');
        $repMsg = $session->get('repMsg');
        $gestRec = $session->get('Reclam');
        $gestMess = $session->get('gestMess');
        $gestMp = $session->get('gestMp');


        return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:changeArticle.html.twig', array('search' => $search,
            'contenu' => $gestCont,
            'gestAcces' => $gestAcces,
            'gestEtat' => $gestEtat,
            'repMsg' => $repMsg,
            'gestRec' => $gestRec,
            'gestMess' => $gestMess,
            'gestMp' => $gestMp,
            'date'=>$date,
            'id'=>$id,
            'title'=>$title,
            'content'=>$content,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: who is `corps`?

Comment: corps is a name of a texteara in twig template. {'content':corps}

Answer (score 0):

Look at your route definition `/content/articles/changeArt/{id}/{title}/{content}/{date}` you can see this route expected exactly 4 params. Then, look at the generated path `/content/articles/changeArt/3/test3/%3Ci%3E%3Cu%20style=%22background-color:%20rgb%28255,%20255,%200%29;%22%3Esdfghyujhgrertjr%22%5Ekrjthbkrkjgjgrhgiebgfjkebvkebvkezbkzbkdzbdkzbckdszb%20sdnckdzb%20nc,de%3C/u%3E%3C/i%3E/11/04/2017`, it has alot of params separated by `/` because your params contains slashes.

When matching the URI with route path, it look like:

```
id:      3
title:   test3
content: %3Ci%3E%3Cu%20style=%22background-color:%20rgb%28255,%20255,%200%29;%22%3Esdfghyujhgrertjr%22%5Ekrjthbkrkjgjgrhgiebgfjkebvkebvkezbkzbkdzbdkzbckdszb%20sdnckdzb%20nc,de%3C
date:    u%3E%3C
         i%3E // how about these extra params?
         11   // 
         04   // 
         2017 //
```

I don't known which Symfony version you're using, it should throw exeption if your params contains `/`. You can solve your problem by encode your params before generate the url.

```
{{ path('changeArticle', {
    id: id,
    title: titre|url_encode,
    content: corps|url_encode,
    date: pub|date('d/m/Y')|url_encode
}) }}
```

Comment: That didn't help :(

Comment: the extra '/' are added to the blob variable content. How can I fix that?? and I changed the date format to ('d-m-Y') to get rid of the date "/"

Comment: In your case, you should move that blob param to the end of route `/content/articles/changeArt/{id}/{title}/{date}/{content}`. Then, accept anything after `date` param ` by adding: `requirements: {content: .+}`

Comment: I got a new Semantical Error: Couldn't find constant requirements

Comment: ah its ,requirements= {"content": ".+"}

Answer (score -1):

Is `'date':pub|date('d/m/Y')` a Typo?

Try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" title="modifier l'article">
    <a 
        href="{{ path('changeArticle',{
            'id' : id,
            'title' : titre,
            'content' : corps,
            'date' : date|date('d/m/Y')
        }) }}" 
        style="color: #ffffee;text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
   </a>
</button>
```

Comment: no no as I said there is no problem with the twig, as you see the variables are passed to the controller successfully (you can see the variables content in the error) so I think the problem is in the action, but I couldn't find it

Comment: no problem with twig?? And why your CSS styles are in the builded URL?

Comment: and for "pub|date('d/m/Y')"  pub is a variable name in twig

Comment: what"s wrong with my css?!!!! the template and the css can not cause a 'Not found route' error

Comment: as I said, everything was working before i change the type of "content" it was a string and i changed it to blob

Comment: `the template and the css can not cause a 'Not found route' error` Outch... Are u sure to know how works Symfony?? Come on...

Comment: The route is in the controller, the template has nothing to do with it, it only redirects to this route by the link path

Comment: and which Route do you try to call? A route who doesn't exist, so you have a 404...

Comment: this is my route : @Route("/content/articles/changeArt/{id}/{title}/{content}/{date}",defaults={"id": 0,"title": 0,"content": 0,"date": 0},name="changeArticle")

Comment: Ok, you don't want to understand. Probably due to a lack of knowledge of the tools you use... Don't want to waste my time anymore...

Comment: I think it's you who don't understand!! All your answers were misleading!! I think that's why you got a downvote. Thanx for trying to help. Bye